# ISIS Proteus - Simulating a buzzer using an Atmega 8535 Micro controller

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, atmega, output, proteus

I am new to micro controller programming.

I am programming a Atmega 8535 micro controller using AVR Studio and simulating the circuit using ISIS Proteus.

In ISIS Proteus, there is a buzzer output device.

I need to know how what the schematic layout needs to be to play a sound using the buzzer. Just a simple layout that will demonstrate the use of the buzzer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert to the schematic a buzzer (from active library), then double click the buzzer to open the properties page and set the voltage you want it to operate in, the frequency it should generate (500HZ is fine actually) and the resistance.
Ideally you want these to match the ones of the real device you want to use but for testing purposes you can set them at will.

The buzzer needs just a DC input voltage to activate, the default is 12v but if you want to feed it with 5v from a pin of the mcu then you can set it in the properties to 5v.

[image: proteus buzzer]